# Angle with the horizontal of the intersection of two planes.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, vectors

The gutters on two roofs meet at right angles and the roofs themselves make angles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the horizontal. Show that the line of intersection of the roofs makes an angle with the horizontal of:

$\arcsin(1/(\sqrt(1+cot^2(\alpha)+cot^2(\beta)))$

Comment: What efforts have you put in ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the two lines, representing the gutters, intersect at the point $C$ and let us take point $S$ on the intersection line of the roofs, such that the segment $SH = 1$, where $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $S$ onto the horizontal plane determined by the two gutter lines. Then the segment $SH$ is orthogonal to the horizontal plane. Let $A$ be the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto one of the gutter lines, and $B$ be the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto the other gutter line (see picture). Since $SH$ is orthogonal to the horizontal plane, it is orthogonal to every line lying in it, in particular $SH$ is orthogonal to $AC$. Since $HA$ is also orthogonal to $AC$, the line $AC$ is orthogonal to the whole plane $AHS$. Since $AC$ is orthogonal to the plane $AHS$, it is orthogonal to every line lying in it, in particular $AC$ is orthogonal to $AS$. Hence, triangle $ACS$ is right-angled.
[image]
Furthermore, since $\angle \, CAH = \angle \, CBH = \angle \, ACB = 90^{\circ}$ the quad $ACBH$ is a rectangle, so $AC = HB$. Since triangle $BHS$ is right-angled and $\angle \, HBS = \beta$
$$HB = SH \, \cot(\beta) = \cot(\beta)$$ and therefore
$$AC = \cot(\beta)$$ Furthermore, triangle $AHS$ is right-angled and  $\angle \, HAS = \alpha$ so
$$AS = \frac{SH}{\sin(\alpha)} = \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)}$$ Consequently, by Pythagoras' theorem for $ACS$
$$SC^2 = AS^2 + AC^2 = \frac{1}{\sin^2(\alpha)} + \cot^2(\beta) =  \frac{\sin^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha)}{\sin^2(\alpha)} + \cot^2(\beta) =$$ $$ = 1+\frac{\cos^2(\alpha)}{\sin^2(\alpha)} + \cot^2(\beta)$$
$$SC = \sqrt{1+\cot^2(\alpha) + \cot^2(\beta)}$$ Since the angle $\gamma$ between the line $SC$ and the horizontal plane $ABC$ is given by the angle $\gamma = \angle \, HCS$, due to the fact that triangle $CHS$ is right-angled
$$\sin(\gamma) = \frac{SH}{SC} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2(\alpha) + \cot^2(\beta)}}$$